# I changed the contact button to red but it's not showing on the first button. What am I missing?

Tags: css

http://studioadesigncollective.com/smoovesalsero/

Heres' the CSS for the button - there's nothing else in the rest of the css that refers to this button.

```
.shortcode_button { 
display:inline-block;
margin:0 10px 10px 0;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
border:2px #555555 solid;   
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
transition: all 400ms;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms;
line-height:20px;
font-size:14px;
padding:10px 21px;
font-weight:700;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align:top;
text-align:center;
}
.shortcode_button.btn_type1 {
    color:#555555;
    background:#fff;
}
.shortcode_button.btn_type1:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    border-color:#aa0935;
    background:#aa0935;
}

.promo_text_block .shortcode_button {
    padding:16px 25px;
    margin-bottom:31px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is:[image]

The question you might be asking is why the selector with the yellow background-color is trumping your own selector with the red background-color. The answer is [selector specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Since the selector in the plugins.css file is looking for three classes, and yours only looks for two, the former wins, or gets to apply its style.

How to fix it? If possible, remove the offending style, or change the naming of your class to something the offending style won't be applied to, such as `button_yellow`.

Hope this helps!